# Two forms one is updating database other not (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

I have two forms on a one page website - subscription to a newsletter and a contact form. I've used similar pattern to be able to submit the user's input to the database. On the top of that using validate.js I'm experiencing the following issues:

- Newsletter subscription - submitting input to the database and displaying the thank you message, but validation.js stopped working, so basically submitting even if it's not an email.
- Contact form - Displaying the thank you message after submission, must be connecting to the database, but submitting empty fields.

Newsletter submission form:

```
<form novalidate type="" action="http://local.project/thankyou_newsletter.php?form=email" method="post" class="newsletter__form-js">
```

Contact form:

```
<form novalidate type="" name="contact_form" class="contact__form__wrapper" method="post" action="http://local.project/thankyou_contact.php?form=email">
```

thankyou_newsletter.php

```
<?php

require 'connection.php';
$conn    = Connect();
$email   = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$query   = "INSERT into newsletter (email) VALUES('" . $email . "')";
$success = $conn->query($query);

if (!$success) {
    die("Couldn't enter data: ".$conn->error);

}

echo "Thank you for subscribing to our newsletter. <br>";

$conn->close();

?>
```

thankyou_contact.php

```
<?php

require 'connection.php';
$conn    = Connect();
$name    = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$email   = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$message = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['message']);
$query   = "INSERT into contactForm (name, email, message) VALUES('" . $name . "','" . $email . "','" . $message . "')";
$success = $conn->query($query);

if (!$success) {
    die("Couldn't enter data: ".$conn->error);

}

echo "Thank you for your message. We will get back to you shortly. <br>";

$conn->close();

?>
```

connection.php

```
<?php

function Connect()
{
 $dbhost = "localhost";
 $dbuser = "root";
 $dbpass = "root";
 $dbname = "responses";

 // Create connection
 $conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname) or die($conn->connect_error);

 return $conn;
}

?>
```

Comment: _empty fields_ What fields? You have only posted the head of the form

Comment: I've just posted the answer. In fact it was not empty, but '0'.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem was in the database I set up. I was doing it in phpMyAdmin and haven't changed the field type to 'varchar'.